# Syntax highlighting for perl not inferred from tag

Tags: support, tags

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28275/manually-assign-a-value-when-inet-ntoa-does-return-an-ip-address) didn't get automatic syntax highlighting for the Perl code, although it is tagged [perl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perl).
Manually adding `<-- language: lang-perl -->` to my answer worked (and I could have done that to the question - left as is for illustration purposes).

Could the tag be updated so that automatic language syntax highlighting kicks in? (Or am I missing something in how that post was formatted that prevented this?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done; all [perl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perl) questions will syntax-highlight as perl now. Prettify is supposed to detect the language by default, but maybe that code block was too short for it to figure it out